# VF page is not Responsive

Tags: apex, user-interface-api

I have a visualforce page and I want to see the page on the mobile version of salesforce.
I checked the checkbox "Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the mobile app   " for the page.

I can see the page but it is not responsive(Alligned properly) on the mobile version.

I did not use any stylesheets for my VF page.

Am I missing anything here. Could some one help making my VF responsive to any screen.

Answer (score 8):

Visualforce, in and of itself, is *not a responsive framework*. The checkbox to make available in lightning and mobile is just that, *it makes the page available*.

If you're looking for a responsive page, you'll either need to use a CSS responsive framework like Twitter's Bootstrap (the old way), or use SLDS (Salesforce Lightning Design System).

In either case, you're probably not going to end up using many of the tags that visualforce provides.